Using fontawesome icons in charts
I am trying to make a scatterplot where instead of dots I have fontawesome icons. I tried the code below but am getting this error message: "! gridtext has encountered a tag that isn't supported yet: < svg >". Is there a way to fix this error?
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(2, 5, 1)
xy <- data.frame(x = x , y = y)

ggplot(xy, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_richtext(aes(label = fa("male")), 
    size = 12, label.colour = NA, fill = NA) +
  theme_minimal()

